# Wordpress and Unity high scores table

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, database, users

I am trying to figure out what is going to be my best route to go in this choice. I have a Unity game I have integrated with Wordpress but I need to send and receive the high scores of the game in the WP database.

1. Should I create my own table in WP to store my high scores along with the user information of people who have signed up.
2. Should I use Custom Post Types to store this kind of information instead of a my own table in WP?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a custom table for this.

Otherwise you'd have to have a lot of custom post types posts containing very little information. Your own table is easier to manipulate (and, god forbid, export should you want to use another high score solution).

Comment: Many thanks Jobjorn. I have just been watching a number of videos this morning on Custom Post Types and although I see the power of it, it may not work in my own situation.

I will created another question about how to add a table and keep the scores saved. Many thanks